# Symfony2: generateUrl() for a route using a ParamConverter or how to reverse parameter conversion

Tags: symfony, routes

I'm using a custom ParamConverter in my route, not only to keep the controller lean but to reuse the parameter conversion algorithm. It uses a route parameter as the index of a hash map and sets the request parameter to the corresponding value. Works like a charm.

```
class EntityParamConverter implements ParamConverterInterface
{
    protected $classNames;

    public function __construct($classnames = array())
    {
        $this->classNames = $classnames;
    }

    function apply(Request $request, ParamConverter $configuration)
    {
        $options = $configuration->getOptions();
        $paramName = $configuration->getName();
        $nameParam = isset($options['entity_name']) ? $options['entity_name'] : 'entityname';

        if (empty($request->get($nameParam))) {
            return false;
        }

        $entityName = $request->get($nameParam);

        if (empty($this->classNames[$entityName])) {
            return false;
        }

        $entityClass = $this->classNames[$entityName];
        $request->attributes->set($paramName, $entityClass);

        return true;
    }

    function supports(ParamConverter $configuration)
    {
        return empty($configuration->getClass());
    }
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to generate the URL for that route from within the controller without having to tell the controller about the hash map. Is there a way to reverse ParamConversion or is this the wrong approach to begin with?